# Can't properly align my receipt lines

Tags: c#

I am having problems aligning 2 variables in a receipt I am building with Graphics.DrawString(). I am trying to achieve:

```
<indent>Cash....................500.00
<indent>Master Card............1000.00
<indent>American Express.....10,000.00
```

This is what I currently have

```
foreach (var item in GC.PAYMENT_Repo) //Entity framework
{
    int typeLength = item.type.Length;
    int amountLength = item.amount.Length;

    Graphics.Drawstring("    " + item.type.PadRight(20, '.') + item.amount.PadLeft(typeLength));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up a `Rectangle` for each columns and also setting a `StringFormat` to control alignment? Also what `font` do you use?

Comment: I didn't include the font in the code but it is courier new at size 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working concept using `Rectangle` and `StringFormat` to align your text. The sample below must be in `OnPaint()` of a `Control` or `PrintDocument`. You can also create a `Form` and override the `OnPaint` and paste the code below:

```
List<dynamic[]> rows = new List<dynamic[]>();           
rows.Add(new dynamic[] { "Cash", 500 });
rows.Add(new dynamic[] { "Master Card", 1000 });
rows.Add(new dynamic[] { "American Express", 10000 });

Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Font f = new Font("Courier New", 8f);
//1st column
StringFormat sf1 = new StringFormat();
sf1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
sf1.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

//2nd column
StringFormat sf2 = new StringFormat();
sf2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
sf2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    int x = 10; //Change for indentation (where you want the x position), currently 10px 
    int y = f.Height * i;
    int colWidth = 125; //You can change this to set each column's width
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x, y, colWidth, f.Height);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(r1.Right, y, colWidth, f.Height);

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r1); //Just to debug rect area
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r2);

    g.DrawString(rows[i][0], f, Brushes.Black, r1, sf1);
    g.DrawString(rows[i][1].ToString("0.00"), f, Brushes.Black, r2, sf2);
}
```

The idea is you use the `Rectangle` area to specify the actual position of your text where you want it to be printed. While `StringFormat` helps in the alignment.